# How can I join SQL subqueries as they are?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 subqueries that when executed independently they all return 3 rows with the desired columns and values. Once I put them all in the from statement and select them all

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROUND(Verbrecher / Buerger * 100, 1) AS Sicherheitsgrad 
FROM 
    (SELECT name AS Dorf 
     FROM dorf 
     GROUP BY dorfnr) AS Dorf,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Verbrecher 
     FROM bewohner 
     WHERE status LIKE 'boese' 
     GROUP BY dorfnr) AS Verbrecher, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Buerger 
     FROM bewohner 
     GROUP BY dorfnr) AS Buerger
```

This is the result of all three subqueries being respectively executed standalone

[Standalone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isa1z.png)

This is the result

[Snippet above being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMLod.png)

I expect them to be joined together and have three rows with the queries aligned horizontally.

That unfortunately is not the given result.

I hope this makes sense to a certain extent.

Comment: _I expect them to be joined together and have three rows_. No. The result will consist of `x * y * z` rows where x, y, z represent the number of rows in each sub query. Post more information about your problem, but not as images

Comment: Hmmm. And how could that be bypassed

Comment: Yes thats right is just didn't want to include all three queries... imagine that x3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need in this:

```sql
SELECT dorfnr, Dorf, Verbrecher, Buerger,
       ROUND(Verbrecher / Buerger * 100, 1) AS Sicherheitsgrad 
FROM ( SELECT dorfnr, name AS Dorf 
       FROM dorf 
--       GROUP BY dorfnr
       ) AS Dorf
JOIN ( SELECT dorfnr, COUNT(*) AS Verbrecher 
       FROM bewohner 
       WHERE status LIKE 'boese' 
       GROUP BY dorfnr
       ) AS Verbrecher USING (dorfnr)
JOIN ( SELECT dorfnr, COUNT(*) AS Buerger 
       FROM bewohner 
       GROUP BY dorfnr
       ) AS Buerger USING (dorfnr)
```

Comment: dorfnr is ambiguous

Comment: Wow didnt expect that to work. Thank you sir!

Comment: @nbk *dorfnr is ambiguous* ? why?

Comment: it procuces an error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4735bd747036e4f751123685ef0e926a

Comment: @nbk Error source is unneeded GROUP BY in `Dorf` subquery. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7410e4e7fc46c57856db231f11efeebb This occures because I have copied and edited the source query without analyzing it completely. Thanks. Fixed.